# Running javascript code on page load, without using the onload tag

Tags: javascript

How can I run a JavaScript code when the page loads without using the `onload` tag?

I'm trying to run this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayLightbox() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'
}
</script>
```

That displays a lightbox.

Comment: Is there any reason for doing this?

Comment: Yes, I am developing for a system that for some reason strips the body tag from the onload field.

Comment: @OrW do you mean SharePoint by any chance?

Comment: @OrW: And does the CRM have its own onload script?

Comment: By the way, when replying to comment with comment, use `@` to notify the person you're replying to otherwise he/she will never see it.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I am not entirely sure, there's a lot of js code, i'm trying to check now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Like this:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(event) {
    alert("Page is loaded");
}
```

Edit: if some other code is also using `window.onload` after that script then it will be "overwritten" - to make sure it's executed (and abort any other `onload`) put it in the bottom of the page.

Edit 2: On second thought, you better **add** onload listener instead of overwriting it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.addEventListener) { // Mozilla, Netscape, Firefox
    window.addEventListener('load', WindowLoad, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE
    window.attachEvent('onload', WindowLoad);
}

function WindowLoad(event) {
    alert("Another onload script");
}
</script>
```

This will prevent any conflicts with existing code and is more cross browser as far as I can tell.

Live test case is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/GZPTG/ tested for IE8, Chrome and Firefox (latest versions) feel free to test for more.

Comment: Named function expressions don't work correctly in Internet Explorer 8 and lower, so it's generally best to avoid them.

Comment: @Andy care to elaborate? Quick test in IE8 showed the alert just fine, and used it for IE6 and IE7 in the past as well..

Comment: @Shadow: what I meant was that your function expression will behave differently - in Internet Explorer it will create a function named `WindowLoad`, available to the outer scope whereas in other browsers it will create a function that is not available to the outer scope but can be accessed from within the function by its name.  Other than that it will work just fine, but it's better to leave the name off or use a proper function declaration depending on what you want to do.  A much better explanation is available at http://kangax.github.com/nfe/.

Comment: @Andy thanks, wasn't aware of that. So far it wasn't relevant for me but it's always good to be on top of things. :)

Comment: This is a good answer and all, but `attachEvent()` isn't standardized. As a matter of fact, it was only supported on IE on versions 6-10.

Comment: @hello well, it does check for `addEventListener` first and won't crash if there's no support in `attachEvent` - since many people are still using IE10 and below (mainly in big corporations who take years to upgrade anything) this is still  a good idea to leave it there, in my opinion.

Comment: Ah. Now the real question is this: why are people still using netscape?

Comment: @hello where you saw people using it? According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers), nobody really using it anymore. (i.e. not even recorded.)

Comment: Well, then why is that a thing on the list of browsers?

Answer (score 2):

maybe put a javascript code at the end of the page just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```
.
.
.
<script>
 yourFunctionHere();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: It won't wait for images to get loaded, for one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<head>
<script>
document.onload = function() { /*run code here */}
</script>
</head>
```

A cleaner way would be

```
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('onload',funciton(){
 /* run code here */
});
</script>
</head>
```

since this allows for multiple eventhandlers to the same event

A better way is usually to react to domReady though.

Most javascript libraries support easy ways to hook into domReady. In jQuery for example you can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
/* code here will be run as soon as the dom is ready to be interacted with, 
   but before document.load occurs which means you don't have to wait for 
   images to load for example
*/
});
```

Comment: Code wont work as typed because `function` is misspelled. 'Funciton' sounds like a Japanese robot built to party - "Funky-ton".

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onload function because you will come across less problems when trying to debug it in different browsers.

The only other way I know to simulate this effect reliably is to have a script tag block just before the  at the footer of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Note that commands outside of functions in a script tag in the  header run when the page loads.  I don't know if this is actually equivalent to running functions explicitly *onLoad* via the body tag attribute, but it is tantamount to the same thing.