# div not scrolling to bottom (css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

ok so have some code that I've cobbled together to make some kind of chat room, it's a hack job tbh but learning as I go along. Been through a number of answers here but nothing seems to work.

I want a javascript function to run when the page loads. there is another part of the code that does the same thing when run (it is run when a button is pressed) that does work, so this is confusing me. anyway.

the css:

```
#result{max-width:1024px; width:100%; padding:10px; background: #0000A0; overflow:auto;}
```

the function im trying in the  part of index.php:

```
 function scrollbottom(){   
    document.getElementById('result').scrollTop=document.getElementById('result').scrollHeight;
}
```

I have tried calling the function in the body, calling with window on load, and calling before and after the function within the script tag.

this code does run (also with script tag), and does scroll the div to the bottom, I didn't write this code btw:

```
function submitchat(){
    if($('#chat').val()=='1' || $('#chatbox').val()==' ') return false;
    $.ajax({
        url:'chat.php',
        data:{chat:$('#chatbox').val(),ajaxsend:true},
        method:'post',
        success:function(data){
            $('#result').html(data); // Get the chat records and add it to result div
            document.getElementById('result').scrollTop=document.getElementById('result').scrollHeight; // Bring the scrollbar to bottom of the chat resultbox in case of long chatbox
        }
    })
    return false;
```

};

and that is run from

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return submitchat();">
```

help appreciated and can post more code if needed. With the exception of the CSS file, all the above is in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

onLoad should work. Make sure it's not a dumb mistake like capitalization errors (I accidentally do that all the time!), and other simple problems.

If you find nothing, trying an external way of loading on page load would work. See if this post below will help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722710/6911064

Comment: thanks, I tried this: window.onload = function scrollbottom();

function scrollbottom(){

 document.getElementById('result').scrollTop=document.getElementById('result').scrollHeight;
} but it doesnt work, div doesnt even show now, and also when i used the button that refers to other function the page reloads so not sure whats going on there..